# In PHP, why am I getting the "class name must be a valid object or string" error?

Tags: php, class, oop, debugging, error-handling

```
    <?php
class article{
    public $title='';
    public $text='';
    public $instancesFilesmage='';
    public $currentDate='';
    public $section='';
}
//Definition of article class
for($instancesFiles=0;$instancesFiles<count(scandir("Articles/".date('y-m-d').""));$instancesFiles++){
//For each file inside the directory for today's articles, each of which corresponds to an instance of the "article" class...
        $dir="Articles/".date("y-m-d")."/".($instancesFiles+1)."";
        $artProps=scandir($dir);
    //Retrieve an array of its interior files, each of which corresponds to a property of the aforementioned instance
    for($propertiesFiles=0;$propertiesFiles<count($artProps);$propertiesFiles++){
        //For each item in "artProps", each of which corresponds to a property of the instance
        $instName="".date("y-m-d")."_".($instancesFiles+1)."";
        $$instName=new $article();
        $$instName->$currentDate=''.time().','.date("y-m-d").'';
        //This just sets defines the time and date at which the article was published, the sole property which exists independently from any file
        if(pathinfo($artProps[$propertiesFiles], PATHINFO_BASENAME)=='TITLE'){
            $$instName->$title=fgets($artProps[$propertiesFiles]);
        }
        if(pathinfo($artProps[$propertiesFiles], PATHINFO_BASENAME)=='TEXT'){
            $$instName->$text=fgets($artProps[$propertiesFiles]);
        }
        if(pathinfo($artProps[$propertiesFiles], PATHINFO_BASENAME)=='SECTION'){
            $$instName->$section=fgets($artProps[$propertiesFiles]);
        }
        //3 ABOVE CONDITIONALS:See if it is one of the properties whose definition is found by retrieving the first line of the file, and, if so, get that first line and set the property to that first line
        if(pathinfo($artProps[$propertiesFiles], PATHINFO_BASENAME)=='IMAGE'){
            $$instName->$image=$artProps[$propertiesFiles];
        }
        //1 ABOVE CONDITIONAL:See if it is an image, and set the image property of the particular instance to that file
        echo("<p>{$instName->$title}<p>");  
    }
}
```

?>

I'm getting the "class name must be a valid object or string error" when I first initiate an instance of the "article" class. Why? Does it have to do with me using double variables? How can I get around this?

Comment: `new $article();` must be `new article();`

Comment: You should probably read through: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score -1):

Here issue with `$article()`

In PHP, class name do not have `$` symbol. only variables will have.

and here your try to create a object from variables that is why you are getting error.

update

`$article()` to  `article()`

One more thing here is you declared class name as `article`. Always class name should start with capital latter `Article`. **`Try to follow PHP code standards.`**